# slidify set background with reveal.js framework

Tags: r, reveal.js, slidify

I love the combination of Slidify with the reveal.js framework.

That said, I can't figure out how to change the background to an image or color using slidify.

For reveal.js, I'd just do:

```
<section data-background="#007777">
```

as documented [here](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/13)

I modified the reveal.js [slide layout](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidifyLibraries/blob/dev/inst/libraries/frameworks/revealjs/layouts/slide.html#L4-L8) to include the data-background argument as such:

```
<section class='{{slide.class}}' data-state='{{slide.ds}}' id='{{slide.id}}' data-background='{{slide.background}}'>
```

and call a new slide like this:

```
--- .background "#007777"
```

But no change in the background. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify it as `--- {background: "#007777"}`.

The dot/hash syntax I use is a shortcut for commonly specified slide properties. So `--- .myclass #myid` would actually expand to `--- {class: myclass, myid: id}`. The long-form syntax is more flexible as you can specify any valid YAML after the `---` including lists.

Comment: Thanks - though this still isn't working for me. Where should my 'slide.html' template be? Currently, I'm modifying the one in the slidifyLibraries directory: ~R/3.0/slidifyLibraries/libraries/frameworks/revealjs/layouts/slide.html

Comment: If you use `mode: selfcontained`, the `libraries` folder will get copied to your slide directory and you can then modify `libraries/frameworks/revealjs/layouts/slide.html`. Alternately, you could add your modified `slide.html` to `assets/layouts` and it will automatically override the default.

Comment: DO NOT modify the layout in `~R/3.0/...` since it is bound to get rewritten when you update. Safest way is to do what I suggested in my earlier comment.

Comment: Really appreciate the help on this, but still not getting it. I've created an example [here](https://github.com/johnstantongeddes/slidify-reveal-test/blob/gh-pages/index.html) with this [output](http://johnstantongeddes.github.io/slidify-reveal-test/#/1). You can see that I have "data-background="#007777" in the html but it's still not appearing when I view the page.

Comment: I see that the template has picked up the background correctly. I believe that the `data-background` attribute was introduced in a later version of revealjs. Quick fix will be to replace the `reveal.min.js` file in `libraries/frameworks/revealjs` with the latest version of reveal. Do the same with the CSS file. I will update reveal when I next work on `slidifyLibraries`.

Comment: Beautiful - that did it!

Comment: Great! Can you file an issue at `slidifyLibraries` so that I remember to update `revealjs`? Thanks.